# Surjections on generalized homology theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

In Davis-Januszkiewica´s paper [Hyperbolization of polyhedra](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214447212) , the authors hyperbolized every closed n-manifolds K to get a new manifold, say M(K),together with a map $f_K$ from M(K) to K, then they claimed that $f_K$ induces a surjection on any generalized homology theory.(see Theorem B in the introduction)

According to the authors, this claim is the result of combining two facts:

1. For any homology with local coefficients, $f_K$ induced an injection.
2. $f_K$ pulls back the stable tangent bundle of M(K) to the stable tangent bundle of K.

I don´t know how to deduce the claim from these two facts. Without backgrounds on generalized homology theory,  I only know some basic definitions such as stable tangent bundle, so I don´t understand how these two facts can be used in generalized homology theory.

Can anyone gives some details? Thank you.

Comment: It seems you have misquoted the paper slightly. They actually talk about an "asphericalization" $f_K:a(K)\to K$, so the map goes the other way. The claim that $f_K$ induces a surjection on any generalized homology theory is then supposed to follow from (2') $f_K$ injective on ordinary homology, and (4) $f_K$ pulls the stable tangent bundle of $K$ back to that of $a(K)$.

Comment: @MarkGrant Yes , Thanks, I will edit it.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that (2') has a typo, and "into" should be "onto".

Otherwise the statement is of course not true: the degree $d$ map $S^2 \to S^2$ is injective on homology with all local coefficients, and pulls back the stable tangent bundle of $S^2$ to that of $S^2$, as both are trivial. But it of course not surjective on ordinary homology.